# WooCommerce product category page is blank

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom archive-product template for displaying my product categories with headers in the shop front page. It also allows me to hide certain categories from the shop page. These edits were applied to the newest version of the archive-product.php. The problem is that when I go to the specific category page, no products are shown, it is just blank. If I revert the archive-product template back to default, the product category pages are then populated. Below is the php added to the template, is there something that seems to be wrong with it?

Thanks!

```
<?php
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

    /* Category - SubCategory START */
                $term           = get_queried_object();
                $parent_id      = empty( $term->term_id ) ? 0 : $term->term_id;

                $excludedCats = array(47);

                $product_categories = get_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'child_of' => $parent_id, 'exclude' => $excludedCats) );

                $i = 1;
                foreach ($product_categories as $product_category) {
                    echo '<h2>'.$product_category->name.'</h2>';
                    woocommerce_product_loop_start(); //open ul

                    $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'tax_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => $product_category->slug
                            ),
                        ),
                        'post_type' => 'product',
                        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                        'order' => 'asc',
                    );
                    $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();
                        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                    endwhile; // end of the loop.
                wp_reset_postdata();
                woocommerce_product_loop_end(); //close ul
                if ( $i < count($product_categories) )
                    echo '<div class="content-seperator"></div>';
                $i++;
                }//foreach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 - Try using following code and let me know if it works


                $obj           = get_queried_object();

                        if(is_shop()){
                            $parent_id  = empty( $obj->parent  ) ? 0 : $obj->parent;
                        }else if(is_product_category()){
                            $obj  = get_queried_object();
                            $parent_id  = empty( $obj->term_id  ) ? 0 : $obj->term_id; 
                            $cat_slug   = empty( $obj->slug  ) ? 0 : $obj->slug;

                        }                

                        $excludedCats = array(47);

                        if($parent_id != 0){
                            $product_categories = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat','slug'=>$cat_slug,'exclude' => $excludedCats) );


                        }else{
                            $product_categories = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'exclude' => $excludedCats) );

                        }

                        $i = 1;
                        foreach ($product_categories as $product_category) {
                            echo '<h2>'.$product_category->name.'</h2>';
                            woocommerce_product_loop_start(); //open ul

                            $args = array(
                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $product_category->slug
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'post_parent' => $product_category->parent,
                                'post_type' => 'product',
                                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                                'order' => 'asc',
                            );
                            $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                            while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();
                                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                            endwhile; 
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
                        if ( $i < count($product_categories) )
                            echo '<div class="content-seperator"></div>';
                        $i++;
                        }
```